# Troubles with loading an URL/API including an array - javascript/p5js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have some troubles with a codeline I want to generalize in p5js.
I want to load some data from an URL/API. At the upper line `kursMin[1]...` I get the correct value (stock value). At the lower line `kursMin[i]` I get the output `[object Object]2021-03-124. close`
For me it's the same input with the difference that the lower line is more general.
**Does anyone know where my problem is?** (I'm sorry about my simple enunciation but I'm a beginner with p5js) 
I've been looking for a long time to find a solution but unfortunaley I didn't. I also tried many code combinations within the lower line, (like `"" [] ''`) but nothing works.

```
function kursMinus() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    kursMin[1] = dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[1]]['4. close']; //works
    kursMin[i] = dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'] + [dateMin[i]] + ['4. close']; //doesn't work
  }
}
```

I learned that the `[]` are required because of the space within the path. 
In the preload-function I defined dailyLong as:

```
dailyLong = loadJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&outputsize=full&apikey=demo");
```

I defined the array as `var kursMin = [];`

Comment: Totally confused, in first statement you are reading nested property value but in second statement you are concatenation all the three values. The equivalent to first statement would be `kursMin[i] = dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[i]]['4. close']`. why are you concatenating? what is the structure of dailyLong object ? and your expected result?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. <br/> If I type the line you mentioned i get this in the console `dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[i]] is undefined`. <br/> You can see the structure of the dailyLong object in the link I mentioned in my question. <br/> the expected result will be 134.5900 (for i=1)

Comment: Can you also show how you have defined the array `dateMin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue, I think, is that you think you're working with an Array but you're not.

The data loaded into `dailyLong` is an object. I believe you're getting confused because the keys in `dailyLong` need to be accessed, as you noted, via bracket notation `[]` due to the spaces (`Time Series (Daily)`) and special characters (`2021-04-12`). You can [read more about property accessors here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Based on your code, I have to assume that you have an array of the dates you're trying to search, `dateMin`, and this is what you're trying to loop through to get the daily closing prices (so that *is* an array).

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do with the second line, but if you're just trying to loop through all the closing prices, just remove the `+` signs from the assignment (see code snippet below).

Your first line is correct, because it access the object using bracket notation instead of dot notation. Just change the `1` to `i`. The second line is incorrect (for what you're trying to accomplish), as shown below:

```js
const dailyLong = {
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-04-12": {
      "4. close": 123
    }
  }
}
// Correct, works:
dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[1]]['4. close']

// Not incorrect, but not what you're trying to do:
dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'] + [dateMin[i]] + ['4. close']

// First you get a reference to the object
const object = dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'] // [object Object]
// Second you create a new array with 1 element, dailyMin[i] or '2021-04-12'
const array1 = [dailyMin[i]] // 2021-03-12
// Finally you create a second array with one element, '4. close'
const array2 = ['4. close'] // 4. close

object + array1 + array2 // [object Object]2021-03-124. close
```

Here's a code snippet to show how you can loop through these values:

```js
const dailyLong = {
  "Meta Data": {
      "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
      "2. Symbol": "IBM",
      "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-04-12",
      "4. Output Size": "Full size",
      "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
      "2021-04-12": {
          "1. open": "135.0200",
          "2. high": "135.3700",
          "3. low": "133.8500",
          "4. close": "134.5900",
          "5. volume": "3753959"
      },
      "2021-04-09": {
          "1. open": "134.8700",
          "2. high": "135.7400",
          "3. low": "134.7100",
          "4. close": "135.7300",
          "5. volume": "3023916"
      },
      "2021-04-08": {
          "1. open": "134.5700",
          "2. high": "135.6299",
          "3. low": "134.1600",
          "4. close": "135.1200",
          "5. volume": "4087228"
      },
      "2021-04-07": {
          "1. open": "133.8400",
          "2. high": "134.9400",
          "3. low": "133.7800",
          "4. close": "134.9300",
          "5. volume": "2976136"
      },
      "2021-04-06": {
          "1. open": "135.5800",
          "2. high": "135.6400",
          "3. low": "134.0900",
          "4. close": "134.2200",
          "5. volume": "3620964"
      },
    }
}

const dateMin = [
  '2021-04-12',
  '2021-04-09',
  '2021-04-08',
  '2021-04-07',
  '2021-04-06',
]

function kursMinus() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[1]]['4. close']); //works
    console.log(dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[i]]['4. close']); //works
    // kursMin[i] = dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'] + [dateMin[i]] + ['4. close']; //doesn't work
  }
}

kursMinus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your detailed answer. 
The thought behind `dateMin` was to go monthly steps in the past. If the last refreshment was on 2021-04-12 `dateMin[i]` should be 2021-03-12, 2021-02-12 and so on. 
My mistake was in a wrong interpretation of the error message `dailyLong['Time Series (Daily)'][dateMin[i]] is undefined` 
I thought that the error occurs because of the wrong notation of the URL. 
Indeed the error occurs because the value of the date 2020-12-12 could not be found in the data (2020-12-12 was not a trading day therefore there is no data entry for this day) 
So I have to create a function which reduce the day by 1 until the last trading day is found.